# EF Model: ICollection not read from DB - what could I be missing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am working through some beginner tutorials for ASP.NET Core, and I have managed to build an application with two tables, which have a parent-child (1:n) relation.

Creating the data and saving it works, and the data in the DB *is* correct.

The problem comes when I now click on the details view, where I do the usual

```
    ...
    <dt>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Associations)
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Association</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Associations)
        {
          <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
      </table>
    </dd>
```

(expecting to see a table with all associations) - the line `@foreach (var item in Model.Associations)` crashes. In the debugger, I can see that the respective `model.ICollection<Association>` is `null`.

I think I am missing something so the read of the object from the database does not automatically include the array with Associations - all data of my model object is read and available; just not the ICollection content.

The whole code was created using Scaffolding, and supposedly should be working right away. *Lazy Read* was a potential reason, but even after I changed that, it did not work.

I assume this is a bloody beginner error - I have now about 20 hours total experience with Web development - and I could have well missed some edit in some file that is necessary.

I did spend the last 8 of those 20 looking for this issue, and I recreated the whole app from scratch twice, but the issue is consistently the same. Any tips?

Edit: *not* a duplicate of [Objects in ICollection not passed with model to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031649/objects-in-icollection-not-passed-with-model-to-view) - I worked though it. That is an older framework version, and the syntax that solves this is no longer valid and supposedly no longer needed.

Comment: Ef Core not support lazy loading yet, maybe your problem is that, you can Include Child property for load that. If not solved the problem plz add action code to the question

Comment: remeber that, to use `Include` you need to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to your usings list.